# HTML5 drag N drop without AJAX is it possible?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I try to make a HTML5 uploader without ajax cause i have to create a dir with an input name. I try to make it work like a normal

```
<input type="file" />
```

But i cant get the tmp_name who is in the $_FILES when it's a normal upload. Can i upload only with the file's mozFullPath? There is my code, the dropzone works well.

```
<script>
    var filesUploaded = new Array();

    var dropZoneElement = document.getElementById("dropZone");

    dropZoneElement.addEventListener('dragleave', onDragLeave, false);
    dropZoneElement.addEventListener('dragenter', onDragEnter, false);
    dropZoneElement.addEventListener('dragover', onDragOver, false);
    dropZoneElement.addEventListener('drop', onDrop, false);

    function onDragLeave(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        //you can remove a style from the drop zone

    }

    function onDragEnter(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        //you can add a style to the drop zone
    }

    function onDragOver(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
        event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
    }

    function onDrop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log(event.dataTransfer);
        onFilesSelected(event.dataTransfer.files);
    }

    function onFilesSelected(files) {
        var dropZoneElement = document.getElementById("dropZone");
        for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            filename = files[i]['name'];
            filesrc = files[i]['mozFullPath'];
            filesize = files[i]['size'];
            filetype = files[i]['type'];
            filesUploaded[i] = filesrc;

            var span = document.createElement("span");
            span.setAttribute('class','fileUpload');
            dropZoneElement.appendChild(span);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (files) {
                span.innerHTML = '<i class="icon-file"></i> ' + filename;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        }

    }
</script>
```

Thank you all for your advices and help!

Comment: Javascript is client side...
No, it is not possible to save something to your server without server side scripting.

Comment: Without Ajax? Of course it's possible, just implement a flash or java app uploader then. :) Now if you want to keep your HTML5 clean without flash/java, use Ajax.

Comment: @Daedalus - The question doesn't say anything about not using server-side code, it says "without Ajax". It's tagged "PHP"...

Comment: @nnnnnn I read something wrong.  Oh well.

Comment: Your `FileReader` is superfluous. You're reading the whole file into memory but you're not using the data at all.

Comment: Why so much RAGERS here ? i just said without Ajax and i go -2... I want advice, i don't want to be trolled or bashed. In the tags it says PHP ! and the variable $_FILES is server side...

Comment: If no Ajax you can still use iFrame hacks.

Comment: Ok so you want to just upload some drag and drop files all at once when the user hits submit. you want the ability for the user to drop 3 or 4 files on the page, maybe get a preview? then hit submit and have them all pump to the server? just trying to get some clarity

Answer (score 1):

Don't care about all this. Just use `FormData` and it will take care of constructing the correct headers, which means you'll have the correct `$_FILES` variable server side.

```
var datas = new FormData( 'form-name' );
filesUploaded.forEach( function( file, index ) {
    datas.append( 'file' + index, file );
} );
```

But then, you are forced to send the datas via XHR with the following:

```
xhr.send( datas );
```

Manually constructing the DOM file input element doesn't seem possible. You have no reason not to use AJAX though, there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without using `XMLHttpRequest` and a proper serializer such as [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData).

If you don't want AJAX, you either need Flash/Java or use:

```
<input name="myfiles[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

Comment: This is not my question... i already got the input file...  The variable $_FILES is in a server side... Damn, all here think we are all noobs...

Comment: @MikeBoutin so what's inside your `$_FILES` then? Is it empty?